# Cordova Media-Capture plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-media-plugin, mediacapture

i have made a simple cordova test app to test run the media-capture plugin, nothing happens on the button click of either record audio, capture image or record video

Following are the plugins i have installed in cordova project directory:
[image]

Following is the code for HTML file

```
 <button id = "audioCapture">AUDIO</button>
 <button id = "imageCapture">IMAGE</button>
 <button id = "videoCapture">VIDEO</button>
```

Following is the code for JS file in which i'added the functionality of Audio capture, Image capture and Video capture respectively.

```
document.getElementById("audioCapture").addEventListener("click", audioCapture);
document.getElementById("imageCapture").addEventListener("click", imageCapture);
document.getElementById("videoCapture").addEventListener("click", videoCapture);
function audioCapture() {
    var options = {
        limit: 1,
        duration: 10
    };
    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(onSuccess, onError, options);

    function onSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, path, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

        }
    }

    function onError(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
    }
}

function imageCapture() {
    var options = {
        limit: 1
    };
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(onSuccess, onError, options);

    function onSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, path, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

        }
    }

    function onError(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
    }
}

function videoCapture() {
    var options = {
        limit: 1,
        duration: 10
    };
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(onSuccess, onError, options);

    function onSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, path, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

        }
    }

    function onError(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova must be fully loaded to use the device API

For that cordova provides the deviceready events

In HTML body add `onload` function

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

in JS

```
function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// ready to use device APIs
function onDeviceReady() {
   console.log(navigator.device);
   // document.getElementById("audioCapture").addEventListener("click", audioCapture);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me. I've done this so far but doesn't worked.